# Why does my function need an argument and how to call it with+without?

Tags: python, tkinter, arguments

I have a marvellous function here:

```
def update_config(val):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    fonts_comb = ""
    for i in range(len(fonts)):
        if i == len(fonts) - 1:
            fonts_comb = fonts_comb + fonts[i]
        else:
            fonts_comb = fonts_comb + fonts[i] + ", "
    config["LISTS"] = {"Fonts": fonts_comb}
    config["variables"] = {"font_size": (screen_font_size.var).get(),
                           "x_offset": (x_offset_spin.var).get(),
                           "y_offset": (y_offset_spin.var).get(),
                           "language": language,
                           "preview_font_size": (preview_font_size_spin.var).get()}
    variables = config["variables"]
    if (fonts_menu.var).get() != strings[17]:
        variables["font"] = (fonts_menu.var).get()
    else:
        variables["font"] = font
    if (preview_fonts.var).get() != strings[18]:
        variables["preview_font"] = (preview_fonts.var).get()
    else:
        variables["preview_font"] = preview_font
    with open("config.ini", "w") as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

I don't know if it's relevant, too, but basically it does what the name says - updates the config file.
What I don't like about the function is that it requires an argument (`val`  here, should be `self` maybe?). And 'cause it requires that argument, I can't call it "properly". Let me demonstrate, the following works just fine:

```
class OptionMenus(tk.OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, master, status, *fonts):
        self.var = tk.StringVar(master)
        (self.var).set(status)
        (tk.OptionMenu).__init__(self, master, self.var, *fonts,
                                 command = update_config)
```

However - calling like the following returns this error: `TypeError: update_config() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

```
class Spinboxes(tk.Spinbox):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.var = tk.IntVar()
        tk.Spinbox.__init__(self, master, textvariable = self.var,
                            from_ = 0, to = 100, command = update_config)
```

For now, I have solved it using this:

```
def crossover():
    val = ""
    update_config(val)
```

But it seems to be kind of a monkey-ish way to do things, so is there a better way to call that function?

Comment: The thing is that a `tk.Spinbox` does not pass any arguments to the callback command, but a `tk.OptionMenu` passes the selected value to the callback command. Therefore, if you use the same function it should be able to accept either zero or one arguments. You can do this by using `def update_config(val=None):` like kindall suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a default argument value:

```
def update_config(val=None):
    # etc.
```

You could also remove the argument entirely and use a single-argument `lambda` to call it in a context where that the argument must be passed:

```
def update_config():
    # etc.

# ...

tk.OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *fonts,
                       command=lambda _: update_config())
```

But I think the first option is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

1. `update_config` looks like an instance method, so yes, I recommend using the accepted variable `self`.
2. If an error says it takes 0 arguments but 1 was given, that means exactly what it says. This means that calling `update_config` from the `Spinbox` object passes it an argument. However, since it works fine from `OptionMenus` and therefore works without an argument, you need to set it up to handle an optional argument.

Change:

```
def update_config(val):
```

to:

```
def update_config(self, event=None):
```

and that should fix the issue.

Comment: `Spinbox` still returns an error: `TypeError: update_config() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: Well, is `update_config` an instance method or what? It would've been nice to have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think it's rather a regular (?) method than an instance method, but I'm not very sure. It's not inside a class at all, if that helps.

Comment: If you don't know the difference between functions and instance methods, it would be good to learn about those before continuing. They are fundamental to working with Python (or any OOP language, for that matter).